# Bind value of property to result of some method in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, binding, expression

I need to bind an ASP.NET control something like so:

```
  <asp:label ID="lblName" Text=<%# GetName()) %>
```

and in CodeBehind file I have this method:

```
   protected string GetName()
   {
      ...
   }
```

Is this right, or how I can do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods in code-behind need to be public I believe; I could be wrong, but I've gotten this to work:

```
<asp:label ID="lblName" Text='<%= GetName() %>' />
```

With

```
public string GetName()
{
      ...
}
```

HTH

Comment: in GetName() could you just return "Something" ?

Comment: @Ranhiru, you could return whatever you wanted from this method.  You can return objects too, and then do something like: <%= GetName().PropertyOfObject %>.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server"><%# this.Test() %></asp:Label>
```

The above code assumes that you have a method called Test() with `public` access that returns a `string` in its implementation file.

Comment: Thanks! 
I can write in this way only for default property.
But how about another?

Comment: What do you  mean by *how about another?*? You can access `public` and `protected` property from your markup, but not `private`.